# AspectJ: execution order (precedence) for multiple advice within one aspect

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Classes use compile time weaving.

Imagine I have the aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class SecurityInterceptor {

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
    public void beanAnnotatedWithController() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..)) && args(*,httpReq)")
    public void publicMethods(HttpServletRequest httpReq) {}

    @Pointcut("beanAnnotatedWithController() && publicMethods(httpReq)")
    public void controllerMethods(HttpServletRequest httpReq) {}

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..)) && args(httpReq)")
    public void publicMethodsRequestOnly(HttpServletRequest httpReq) {}

    @Pointcut("beanAnnotatedWithController() && publicMethodsRequestOnly(httpReq)")
    public void controllerMethodsOneArg(HttpServletRequest httpReq) {}


    @Around(value = "controllerMethods(httpReq)")
    public Object populateSecurityContext(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest httpReq) throws Throwable {
        return popSecContext(joinPoint, httpReq);
    }

    @Around(value = "controllerMethodsOneArg(httpReq)")
    public Object populateSecurityContextOneArg(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, HttpServletRequest httpReq) throws Throwable {
        return popSecContext(joinPoint, httpReq);
    }

}
```

What is the correct way to use `@DeclarePrecedence` to determine the execution order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read paragraph "Advice precedence" in the [language semantics](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html) section of the AspectJ documentation.

Precedence of **aspects** can be declared explicitly, precedence of **advice within a single aspect** is determined by rules described in the document and cannot be changed, AFAIK. So `@DeclarePrecedence` will not help you in this case, only changing the order of advice within the aspect file.

Comment: If we cannot change precedence of advice in a single aspect, then will it be better to create different aspects and then order them?

Comment: Either that or just change the lexical order of advices within a single aspect, as I said.

Answer (score 7):

If you're are looking for the the order of multiple aspects, you can create an aspect like:

```
@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("AuthorizationAspect, MySpecialAspect, LastAspect")
public class CoordinationAspect {
    // empty
}
```

This will indeed work over multiple aspects. Inside a single aspect is another matter and can not be changed AFAIK, but I don't see why this would be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong. The original poster asked about execution order of advice within *one* aspect, not about inter-aspect precedence.

Comment: Well, the answer is not wrong per se. I understand that the original question was about the precedence in one aspect, but I clearly stated that in my answer.

Comment: I know you did. I can also explain correctly how to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Java, but that does not make it relevant in this context. :-) No offense meant.

Answer (score 0):

> When two pieces of advice defined in the same aspect both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined (since there is no way to retrieve the declaration order via reflection for javac-compiled classes). Consider collapsing such advice methods into one advice method per joinpoint in each aspect class, or refactor the pieces of advice into separate aspect classes - which can be ordered at the aspect level.

from Spring AOP documentation here (section **6.2.4.7. Advice ordering**) https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html

If it helps in case you came looking for this here.

Comment: OP explicitly asked for help with AspectJ, not Spring AOP.